# How to know which was my last page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

So in WP7 and WP8 I did this in Page2 to know if I had came from Page1:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var lastPage = NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault();

        if (null != lastPage && true == lastPage.Source.ToString().Contains("Page1.xaml"))
        {

        }
    }
```

What to do in WP8.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, you can use the BackStack property of the Frame (current page).

Using the following code you will get the page which originated the navigation to the new page:

```
var lastPage = Frame.BackStack.Last().SourcePageType
```

Comment: If I navigate Back from Second page to first page. Then the page will be deleted from frame, If still I want to know the page name I came back from , How to get?

Answer (score 5):

In WP8.1 RunTime you have a *Frame* class which you use to navigate, there you will also find [BackStack property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.backstack), from which you can read previous pages.

A sample example can look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method checking type of the last page on the BackStack
/// </summary>
/// <param name="desiredPage">desired page type</param>
/// <returns>true if last page is of desired type, otherwise false</returns>
private bool CheckLastPage(Type desiredPage)
{
    var lastPage = Frame.BackStack.LastOrDefault();
    return (lastPage != null && lastPage.SourcePageType.Equals(desiredPage)) ? true : false;
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (CheckLastPage(typeof(MainPage)))
    {
        // do your job
        await new MessageDialog("Previous is MainPage").ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I navigate Back from Second page to first page. Then the page will be deleted from frame, If still I want to know the page name I came back from , How to get?

Comment: @SunilKumarSC Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31002860/2681948).

Comment: Thanks thats all I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

In your OnNavigatedTo function you can use following code to determin your last visited page

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.Frame.BackStack.Count>0)
        {
            var lastPage = this.Frame.BackStack[this.Frame.BackStackDepth - 1];
            string lastPageName = lastPage.SourcePageType.Name;
            if(lastPageName == "MainPage")
             {//This is main page}
        }
  }
```

Comment: If I navigate Back from Second page to first page. Then the page will be deleted from frame, If still I want to know the page name I came back from , How to get?

Answer (score 0):

It works for wp 8.1 silverlight

```
var previousPage = NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault().Source;

if (previousPage!=null && previousPage.ToString().Contains("MainPage"))
  {
    // do your work
  }
```