# How to get info about previous page on Frame.GoBack()

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

Say we have some `Page` PageA and I have a button that, when clicked, does the following:

```
Frame.NavigateTo(typeof(PageB));
```

After the user is done doing stuff, he navigates back from PageB to PageA calling `Frame.GoBack()`

I want be able to determine that I'm navigating back **from PageB**

I could use:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    e.NavigationMode
}
```

But this only tells me that I'm navigating back, not that I'm navigating back from PageB.

Is this even a good windows-phone-guidelines approach (did not find this particular case in the docs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it by using [Frame.ForwardStack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.forwardstack) property which holds forward navigation history.

A short sample which should work:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var lastPage = Frame.ForwardStack.LastOrDefault();
    if (lastPage != null && lastPage.SourcePageType.Equals(typeof(desiredPage)))
        { /* do something */ }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Should be `typeof(desiredPage)`